# Puppet not getting saved with Packer on CentOS 7.1

Tags: puppet, centos7, packer

I am trying to create a Vagrant box using Packer, and everything works fine until I try to install Puppet in the Packer box. The Packer logs clearly says that Puppet is getting installed correctly. However, when I load up the box in Vagrant and SSH into it, Puppet is nowhere to be found (tested this with `yum list | grep puppet`). When I issue the commands that Packer's supposed to execute when creating the box directly on the Vagrant box and run my test command again, Puppet is in fact getting listed there.

I have already tried to rearrange the order of the scripts in the shell provision, but none of this helped at all. The commands to Puppet do seem to be working (seeing that I could get it working directly in the Vagrant box).

I have created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/erikverstegen/19313f554f3d0c230c31) with all of my files. I am installing it on CentOS 7.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things I'd say:

- make sure to cleanup at the really end (run cleanup.sh after puppet.sh)
- `yum list <package>` will list all available packages (and installed packages), to know which packages are installed you should run `yum list installed` (you might have an issue in your repos or mirrors if you do not get any output at all from your command)
- as you installed from rpm, you can also run `rpm -qa | grep puppet` to find out if the package has been installed, you should get something like (depending the version)

  ```
  [vagrant@vagrant ~]$ rpm -qa | grep puppet
  puppetlabs-release-6-11.noarch
  ```

From a quick view, the script looks good - I do install from the following script

```
install_puppet()
{
    echo "==> Installing Puppet"
    REDHAT_MAJOR_VERSION=$(egrep -Eo 'release ([0-9][0-9.]*)' /etc/redhat-release | cut -f2 -d' ' | cut -f1 -d.)

    echo "==> Installing Puppet Labs repositories"
    rpm -ipv "http://yum.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-el-${REDHAT_MAJOR_VERSION}.noarch.rpm"

    if [[ ${CM_VERSION:-} == 'latest' ]]; then
        echo "==> Installing latest Puppet version"
        yum -y install puppet
    else
        echo "==> Installing Puppet version ${CM_VERSION}"
        yum -y install "puppet-${CM_VERSION}"
    fi
}
```

so it does basically the same -

**Update**

Its very strange, I created a box from your gist and the box was okay - puppet was installed.

I only changed from puppet.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
#rpm -ivh https://yum.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-pc1-el-7.noarch.rpm 
rpm -ivh https://yum.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-el-7.noarch.rpm 
yum -y install puppet
```

so I was able to install puppet 3.x rather than puppet 4.x - and I used an existing Vagrantfile with simple provisioning and all was ok

When I vagrant up the VM, provisioning for puppet was running and packaged installed.

Comment: Thanks. I've switched the cleanup and puppet script (which I did just for testing) around and used your script for installing Puppet. It is still not being saved even though the logs of Packer indicating that it was correctly installed. I even ran the `rpm -qa | grep puppet` command in the Puppet script, where I got a correct output (`puppetlabs-release-7-11.noarch`), but this I get no output when I run it with Vagrant.

Comment: hum I would say puppet is correctly installed in your box - what the error when you vagrant up with a puppet provisioning ?

Comment: This is what I get when I run `vagrant up`:

==> default: Running provisioner: puppet...
The `puppet` binary appears not to be in the PATH of the guest. This
could be because the PATH is not properly setup or perhaps Puppet is not
installed on this guest. Puppet provisioning can not continue without
Puppet properly installed.

Comment: weird I made the box from your gist and it looks like its installed, just made a change to install puppet 3.x so I could test with existing provisioning I had

Comment: I've deleted the `.vagrant` and `.vagrant.d` folders from my system, and now it works! Thanks!

Comment: Good but you can also vagrant box add/remove and vagrant destroy VM if you need to keep directory